# GWT addValueChangeHandler to RichTextBox is not allowed, an alternative way required

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to update the database once I have changed the `RichTextBox` and have exited the `RichTextBox` (i.e., I do not want to force the user to press an "Update button"). However, my code throws the exception `The method addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>(){}) is undefined for the type RichTextArea` on the first line.

```
                             textBoxExistingDescription.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
                                public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {

                                    //If a record for this Youth Member specific detail line exists then update it else add it.
                                    if (ymAwardDetails.getYmsdId() != null) {
                                        AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new YMSpecificHandler<Void>(ScoutAwardView.this);
                                        rpc.updateYMSpecific(ymAwardDetails.getYmsdId(), ymAwardDetails.getYmsdDetail(), callback);
                                    }else{
                                        AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new YMSpecificHandler<Void>(ScoutAwardView.this);
                                        rpc.addYMSpecific(youthMemberID, ymAwardDetails.getAdId(), ymAwardDetails.getYmsdDetail(), callback);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Is there an alternative way of doing this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your requirement, I think the same you can also achieve by implementing `addBlurHandler()` instead of `addValueChangeHandler()`.

**Blur event** gets fired when the component loses focus. For more info on blur event, please read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp).

For info on GWT `BlurEvent`, read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/BlurEvent.html).

Answer (score 2):

First, adding plain ValueChangeHandler (even if it was there) will cause your user to send a database request each time he types 1 single character, which is a lot of overhead if you ask me

Saving a backup each time focus is lost may be better, but there's a case where the used didn't click out of the box and still closed the tab somehow, which is non-pleasant.

What I suggest is to:

1. Subclass RichTextArea:

   public class MyRichTextArea extends RichTextArea implements HasValueChangeHandlers {

   ```
       @Override
       public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<String> handler) {
           return this.addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create a timer field inside of subclass.
3. In the constructor for the RichTextBox add keyDown event handler:

If timer is running - prolong it on another 3 seconds, else start timer.

When 3 second timer finished without further keydowns - trigger a service call to save your text. That's how i did it

Comment: I have implemented the solution from @RAS (thanks RAS) and, after a lot of testing, this works for me without the timer. Thanks anyway Pomah.